# Location of SVG source file for folder icon (GNOME)

Tags: gnome, icons, svg

I am looking for the source SVG file for the GNOME icons.  It appears as though most sources redirect people to places like `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/` but the specific icon I am looking for is `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/places/folder.png` ([also available here](https://github.com/GNOME/adwaita-icon-theme/blob/master/Adwaita/48x48/places/folder.png)). This file I can only find in bitmap/png version.

I suspect that this and other icon source files are available in SVG version somewhere.  That is, all icons in the `8x8`, `16x16`, `22x22`,  etc. folders look the same so I imagine they were likely created from an SVG (or similar) file and then exported into a PNG with the desired dimensions.

**Edit:**
Please note that this is the folder icon in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/places`: [image] (converted to 48x48 png as the Stackexchange does not seem to like SVG) while the one I need is this one: [image]

**Second Edit:**
Downloaded the file from the first answer from @andrew.46.  This is real progress.  However, the icon family is not the same as I have installed.  See comparison: [image: Icon comparison]

Icon on left is Adwaita-3.24.0 [from here](https://github.com/GNOME/adwaita-icon-theme/blob/master/src/fullcolor/folders.svg) while the one on the right is the one I have installed.  According to Tweak tool I have the default Adwaita theme installed.  Not sure what Adwaita version this is though.  Maybe someone recognises the icon or can tell me how to check the version.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will the icons in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/places` be of use?

Comment: @DKBose : no, that does not work.  See edit to the question.  I added the closest SVG icon that is at the address you referred to as well as the folder icon whose SVG source I am looking for.  Note that I had to convert the SVG icon to a 48x48 png as the Stack exchange does not seem to like SVG files.

Comment: Try using Inkscape to make your own?

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing this as I would like to edit multiple icons. My fallback approach is to use the one with the highest resolution to create an SVG that hopefully will be of good quality as well (I mostly concerned of the shaded areas as inkscape not always get these correctly when importing a PNG to generate SVG files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I have managed to find the solution.

First, to find the Adwaita version,  I [found the package version using](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-apt-get-aptitude-show-package-version-command/):

> apt-cache policy adwaita-icon-theme

This returned: `Installed: 3.18.0-2ubuntu3.1` (amongst other things).

Using this, I went to https://git.gnome.org/browse/adwaita-icon-theme and downloaded version 3.18 of the Adwaita icon set ([this is the direct link to the whole version 3.18 set](https://git.gnome.org/browse/adwaita-icon-theme/snapshot/adwaita-icon-theme-3.18.0.zip)).

Once unzipped, I went to unzipped folder `adwaita-icon-theme-3.18.0/src/fullcolor/` where I found file `folders.svg`.  One of the icons within is exactly the icon I needed.

All I had to do then was to make a new SVG file and copy/paste the folder icon I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The svg version of this icon (plus friends) can be found in the adwaita-icon-theme source code with the following path:

```
adwaita-icon-theme-3.24.0/src/fullcolor/folders.svg
```

Of course the root directory will change according to which version of the icon theme you use. A direct link to the online source [is here...](https://github.com/GNOME/adwaita-icon-theme/blob/master/src/fullcolor/folders.svg) and a screenshot below:

[image]

Like you I could not find this particular icon installed in an svg version (odd?) so this may be your best option...

Comment: Thank you!  We are getting somewhere.  For some reason, however, the icon family is NOT quite the same so I wonder now what icon theme I have installed (have not changed the default).  I will investigate and edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The **svg gnome app icons** are at:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
```